# Syntax error on class name added to property declaration?

Tags: magento2, error, class

I'm using Magento 2.4.2-p1, Apache 2.4.54, php 7.4, and am getting a `ParseError: syntax error` when a class name is declared with a property declaration - is this expected? is there a work around?

From what I can tell you should be able to use a classname as of 7.4, and the same code is working in an nginx environment:

```
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory;
...
class CreateCustomerGroup
{
    protected GroupInterfaceFactory $groupFactory;
```

Thx for any insights -

Comment: This seems to have been an issue with stale code - I removed `generated/*`, `var/cache` and `var/page_cache` and the error is no longer visible.

Answer (score 0):

Removed generated/*, var/cache and var/page_cache and the error is no longer visible